# Make custom form manually in Django based on a model

Tags: python, django

I am making a basic attendance record system with following models in my `models.py` file : `Department`, `Employee`, `Absence`.

`Absence` model is as below:

```
class Absences(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.ForeignKey(Employees, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    leave_date = models.DateField(null=False)
    leave_type = models.ForeignKey(LeaveTypes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    absence_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    absence_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Now I want to create a form that lets you select date (that will be inserted in `leave_date` column) and a list of all employees with a dropdown (populated with `leave_type`) and submit button (which once clicked with save absences to database based on `Absences` model above.

How do I do this?

Comment: what do you mean with "list of all employees with a dropdown" but "populated with leave_type"?

Comment: I am talking about an HTML table that shows all employees in one column, in next column it shows dropdown (this dropdown shows the type of leave employee is on .e.g casual leave, sick leave; these leaves are got from leave_type model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

You can make insertions directly into a model by simply instantiating an object of the model's class with values you want to insert into the model's table, and then run `.save()` method on that object.

I wanted to make a form that could make multiple entries in `Absences` model (the single entry form is easy to create using `CreateView` class). So I created a template that had the form containing the input fields depending on the number of employees(from `Employees` model) who's attendance needed to be marked. Following is the code of the template's form.

```
     <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="id_leave_date">Date</label>
        <input type="date" name="leave_date" class="form-control" placeholder="Select a date" required="" id="id_leave_date">
        <br>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee</th>
                    <th>Absence</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for emp in emps %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ emp.emp_name }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="{{ emp.pk }}" id="p{{ emp.pk }}" value="present" checked> <label for="p{{ emp.pk }}">Present</label>
                        {% for leave in leaves %}
                        <input type="radio" name="{{ emp.pk }}" id="{{ leave.pk }}{{ emp.pk }}" value="{{ leave.pk }}"> <label for="{{ leave.pk }}{{ emp.pk }}">{{ leave.leave_type }}</label>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Mark Attendance" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
```

To control the template, I created a view `called mark_all_attendance()`. This view showed the above mentioned template if it was accessed with a `GET` request and would send the template info it needed to generate form. If the view was accessed through `POST` request, it would process the submitted form in the template by manually accessing the key-value pairs of submitted form fields by iterating over all the pairs. On each iteration it instantiates objects of `Absences` class using submitted a form field set, and then running the `.save()` method on that object. This inserts the data in field set being iterated over into the `Absences` table. Then redirect the browser to a success page using `HttpResponseRedirect`. Following is the view code:

```
`def mark_all_attendance(request):
submitted = False
all_emps = models.Employees.objects.all()
leaves = models.LeaveTypes.objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':
    leave_date_from_post = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.POST['leave_date'], '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    print('Original: ', request.POST['leave_date'])
    print(leave_date_from_post)
    for key, value in request.POST.items():
        if not (key == 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' or  key == 'leave_date'):
            # print(key + " : " + value)
            if value != 'present': #if present, don't insert record in absences table
                record = models.Absences(
                    emp_id = models.Employees.objects.get(pk=key),
                    leave_type = models.LeaveTypes.objects.get(pk=value),
                    leave_date = leave_date_from_post
                    )
                record.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/attendance/markallattendance?submitted=True')
else:
    if 'submitted' in request.GET:
        submitted = True
return render(request, 'attendance/markallattendance.html', {'emps': all_emps, 'leaves': leaves, 'submitted': submitted})`
```